# Rails scope with associations - optionally filtering scope with properties of associated class

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a task management app where the user can create a "waiting for" on a task.  If the item that they're waiting for hasn't been received, then the task is still active.

I'm trying to set the "actionable" scope to include the tasks that either:

- Have a waiting_for where the received_date is not nil (whatever they were waiting for was received)
  OR
- Don't have a waiting for

  ```
  class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :waiting_fors

  def self.actionable
      where("snooze_date <= ? OR snooze_date IS ?", Time.now, nil ).where(complete: false)
      .includes(:waiting_fors).where("waiting_fors.received_date IS NOT ?", nil)
  end

  class WaitingFor < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :task
  end
  ```

However, it's filtering down to ONLY show me where an item has  a waiting_for AND that waiting_for has a received_date.

Any sugggestions for where I'm going wrong?

UPDATE:

This is what I have now.  It's working if a task either has no waiting fors or has one waiting for that was received.

```
scope :not_snoozed, -> {where("snooze_date <= ? OR snooze_date IS ?", Time.now, nil)}
scope :incomplete, -> {where(complete: false)}
scope :no_waiting_fors, -> {includes(:waiting_fors).where(waiting_fors: {id: nil})}
scope :not_received, -> {includes(:waiting_fors).where.not(waiting_fors: {received_date: nil})}
scope :actionable, -> {incomplete.not_snoozed.where(id: (Task.no_waiting_fors+Task.not_received).map(&:id))}
```

However, if a task has TWO waiting_fors and only ONE has a received date (which means that we're still waiting on something) it's showing up as active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your scopes to this, using the NOT IN feature of SQL:

```
scope :received, -> {includes(:waiting_fors).where("tasks.id not in (select tasks.id from tasks inner join waiting_fors on waiting_fors.task_id = tasks.id where waiting_fors.received_date is null)")} 
scope :actionable, -> {incomplete.not_snoozed.where(id: (Task.no_waiting_fors+Task.received).map(&:id))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
where("waiting_fors.received_date = ?", nil)
```

instead of

```
where("waiting_fors.received_date IS NOT ?", nil)
```

Comment: No, I mean `= ?", nil`.  `received_date` is when the user receives the `waiting_for` item, which marks it complete.  'actionable' tasks are ones that either don't have a `waiting_for` (in other words, `@task.waiting_fors.count = 0`) OR they have a `waiting_for` that has been received (`received_date IS NOT ?", nil`).

Comment: Oh, that is the opposite of what you are writing in your question. Will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AWM - Sorry!  Now I see why you had a question - I made an error in the initial question.  Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

All of this is easily doable with named scopes. You construct a scope for different conditions and then you combine scopes if you want to use multiple conditions. Are you using Rails 4? This would be the syntax:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :waiting_fors
scope :no_waiting_fors, -> {includes(:waiting_fors).where(waiting_fors: {id: nil})}
scope :not_received, -> {includes(:waiting_fors).where.not(waiting_fors: {received_date: nil})}
scope :actionable, -> {where(id: (Task.no_waiting_fors+Task.not_received).map(&:id))}
end
```

Like this you get a flexible and expandable configuration.

Comment: Thanks @AWM. However, it's still returning tasks with an active `waiting_for`.  (Meaning, a waiting_for where the receieved_date is not nil - it wasn't received yet, so the task isn't actionable.)

Comment: Ok, I found a small bug in the code. But I don't think that was the problem. Can you try the new code? If it is not working, please report whether the scopes `no_waiting_fors` and `not_received` are working as they should.

Comment: Changed it again to include tasks with: `received_date` NOT nil
Is it correct this time? Your wording is a little bit confusing ;-)

Comment: Probably, the first and the last scope are obsolete, because `not_received` will already yield what you were searching for.

Comment: so close!  Now it works if the task has one waiting_for which was received, but it's still showing up as active if the task has two waiting_fors and only one was received.  I updated the question with the scopes that I have now.